# How to convert a javascript variable to XML as an alert?

Tags: javascript, xml

I have seen various related topics on this but none of the answers seemed to work and/or were not relevant to my exact problem.

I have a string of data that is formatted by my script and saved as a var. An example of the variable once formatted outputs something like this:

ABC,123,XXXXXX,22,MARK,XXXX.DEF,345,XXX,XX,46,ORL,093782

with the start of each new set being denoted by '.' (except the first value) and each piece of data within the set being separated with ','.  This same format continues with about 15 more entries, with no uniform size of entries, some containing 3-4 pieces of data and some having 10 or more.

I want to be able to output that data as an alert( ) that reads something like the following:

```
<Group>
    <Set name = "ABC">
        <Entry name = "1">123</Entry>
        <Entry name = "2">XXXXXX</Entry>
        <Entry name = "3">22</Entry>
        <Entry name = "4">MARK</Entry>
        <Entry name = "5">XXXX</Entry>
    </Set>
    <Set name = "DEF">
        <Entry name = "1">345</Entry>
        <Entry name = "2">XXX</Entry>
        <Entry name = "3">XX</Entry>
        <Entry name = "4">46</Entry>
        <Entry name = "5">ORL</Entry>
        <Entry name = "6">093782</Entry>
    </Set>
</Group>
```

**Question:** How do I go about this?

Comment: Create a Group node with JS. Then I would split your data string into an array based on every ".". Then you will have each set. Now you can iterate through the array of sets. For each set iterate and split that string into an array on every ",". Now iterate through each entry, create an xml "entry" node and add it to the Set parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<Entry`s have end tags of `</Set>`s, I'm assuming that's just a typo?

Since you say you want to output the data in an *alert*, you just need a string, which is easy to build using the Array methods:

```js
const input = 'ABC,123,XXXXXX,22,MARK,XXXX.DEF,345,XXX,XX,46,ORL,093782';
const allSetsStr = input.split('.')
  .map(commaSeparatedStr => commaSeparatedStr.split(','))
  // if you want to filter out sets with an entryName of 345:
  .filter(([, ...entryNames]) => !entryNames.includes('345'))
  .map(([setName, ...entryNames]) => {
    const allEntrysString = entryNames
      .map((entryName, entryI) => `    <Entry name = "${entryI}">${entryName}</Entry>`)
      .join('\n');
    return `  <Set name=${setName}>
${allEntrysString}
  </Set>`;
  })
  .join('\n');
const outputStr = '<Group>\n' + allSetsStr + '\n</Group>';
console.log(outputStr);
```

Comment: One more question I have is how would I go about omitting a certain Set but only if it contained a specific value in its entries? So don't console.log the entire Set "ABC" but only if within that instance of ABC there is an element equal to "321" or something like that.

Comment: Just `filter` the split `commaSeparatedStr` before proceeding to map it - filter out sets if entryNames contains `321`.

Comment: Could you edit your current answer to represent that?

Comment: Okay so that works to an extent, but how would I also check if the set name ="ABC" because its filtering out sets that dont start with ABC but contain "321".

Comment: I was able to add set within the filter with the || operator and it worked.